# How to start a component in a loop and close it all 3 iterations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Hello i search solution for open tag in loop and close it all the 3 iteration. The goal is to create a grill based on container row and col. My problem is I do not know how to do.

Exemple :

```js
    render(){
        const arrayName = ["john", "bob", "joe", "mat", "toto", "tata"]
        let arrayEl = [];
        let count = 1; 
          for ( let i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++ ) {
             let name = arrayName[i]

             if (count === 1) {
                 arrayEl.push(<div className="row">);
                 arrayEl.push(<p className="col">{name}</p>);
                 count ++;
                 continue;
             }
             if (count === 3) {
                 arrayEl.push(<p className="col" >{name}</p>);
                 arrayEl.push(</div>);
                 count = 1;
                 continue;
             }
           }
        return (<div className="container">{arrayEl}</div>)
    }
```

and the result wanted is :

```html
<div className="container">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col">john</div>
        <div className="col">bob</div>
        <div className="col">joe</div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col">mat</div>
        <div className="col">toto</div>
        <div className="col">tata</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

thank you for some help

**EDIT**

The problem is we can't add someone element or componant without close it.

*is Bad :*

```
arrayEl.push(<div className="row">)
```

*is good :*

```
arrayEl.push(<div className="row"/>) or arrayEl.push(<div className="row"></div>)
```

Comment: Just a note: The wanted result differs from the JSX. You're using `<p>` elements for `.col` and adding `{name}`.

Comment: So you don't care about names ? just 2 rows with 3 columns inside ?

Comment: You refer to both `arrayEL` and `arrayEl`, but only declared `arrayEl`. Your loop uses `,` instead of `;` to seperate conditions. `count` is always set to `0`, so `count++` will make it `1`, but then it becomes `0` again in the next loop. Therefore `(count === 3)` is never reached. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrm0dpwz/1/).

Comment: thx i have whrite this exemple for explain my problem. Sorry for syntaxe error i edit my post but this is not my problem.

Comment: How about the count being defined in the loop? That's not a syntax error. Also, `arrayEl.push(<div className='row'>)` is invalid syntax. **You can only push a starting AND closing tag**. Not by parts like you're doing in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your data from:

```js
 ["john", "bob", "joe", "mat", "toto", "tata"]
// to
 [["john", "bob", "joe"], ["mat", "toto", "tata"]]
```

> Checkout https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chunk for example of that

And then you can nest 2 `.map` to replicate the structure in JSX:

```
const chunk = (arr, chunckSize) => arr.reduce((chunks, value, index) => {
  const chunckIndex = Math.floor(index / chunckSize)
  const c = chunks[chunckIndex] || (chunks[chunckIndex] = [])
  c.push(value)
  return chunks
}, [])

render() {
    const arrayName = ["john", "bob", "joe", "mat", "toto", "tata"]

    return (
        <div className="container">
            {chunk(arrayName, 3).map(names => (
                <div className="row">
                    {names.map(name => <div className="col">{name}</div>)}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `className`, not `class`!

Comment: You're missing a parentheses to close off the first map function.

Comment: i can't modif structure data

Comment: @A.Vincent It's not a modification of the original data, you make a copy, i'll add a chunck implementation so you can test

Comment: @kigiri thx so much but don't lost time i understand your solution and i know how implement her but i want know if an other solution exist

Answer (score 1):

You can't push HTML elements in parts, e.g.

```
arrayEl.push(<div>)

arrayEl.push(</div>)
```

You have to push the elements from start to end, e.g.

```
arrayEl.push(<div>{children}</div>)
```

Therefor you need to instantly output all `cols` in `row`, like the code example below.

```
render() {
    const arrayName = ["john", "bob", "joe", "mat", "toto", "tata"];
    let rows = [];
    let currentCols = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
        let name = arrayName[i];
        currentCols.push(<div className="col" key={i}>{name}</div>);

        if ((i+1) % 3 === 0) {
          rows.push(<div className="row" key={i}>{currentCols}</div>);
          currentCols = [];                
        }
    }

    rows.push(currentCols);
    return (<div className="container">{rows}</div>)
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tjg3w51o/)

Instead of using a `count` variable, I just used the `i` variable from your loop and checked whether or not `(i + 1)` is dividable by 3: `% 3 === 0`. If that is the case, it means you already have 3 cols in your row; We can push the `currentCols` to the `rows` array and empty it.

Comment: I like this solution to

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have to change the logic on your loop in order to get the result you want. Here's what I made as an example with JavaScript. You just need to adapt it with your component.

```js
const arrayName = ["john", "bob", "joe", "mat", "toto", "tata"];
let arrayEl = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
  let name = arrayName[i];
  if ((i % 3) == 0) {
    arrayEl.push(`<div className = "row">\n`);
  }
  arrayEl.push(`<p className = "col">${name}</p>\n`);
  if (((i + 1) % 3) == 0) {
    arrayEl.push(`</div>\n`);
  }
}
console.log(`<div className="container">\n ${arrayEl.join(' ')}</div>`);
```

Comment: the problem is not break or continue, the problem is we can t push (<Row>) without closing it

Comment: `arrayEL.push(</div>)` this is invalid syntax.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko is true this is the problem.. ```arrayEL.push(<div>)``` to

Comment: @YuryTarabanko i search the solution

Comment: @A.Vincent I'm sorry if my new solution isn't correct, I don't know much about react, but I do know about JavaScript, hope it helps

Comment: I test your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that `JSX` is not html so `</div>` expression is invalid.

Imperative approach for the sake of completeness. :)

BTW you need keys.

```
render(){
    const arrayName = ["john", "bob", "joe", "mat", "toto", "tata"]
      let arrayEl = [];
      let row = [];
      const batchSize = 3
      for ( let i = 0, i < arrayName.length, i++ ) {
         const name = arrayName[i]
         row.push(<div className="col" key={name}>{name}</div>)

         // we have a full batch or the last element 
         if (row.length === batchSize || i === arrayName.length - 1) { 
           arrayEl.push(<div className="row" key={i/batchSize}>{row}</div>)
           row = []
         }
       }
    return (<div className="container">{arrayEl}</div>)
}
```